# Как вернуть кнопке дефолтный вид после перекрашивания?

Tags: java, swing

Клик мыши по кнопке приводит к ее перекрашиванию следующей строкой:

```
jbtn.setBackground(new Color(60, 240, 90));
```

Далее мне нужно вернуть этой кнопке дефолтный вид. Но я не могу найти как это сделать. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая команда делает такое действие?

Имеется в виду ее голубая градиентная окраска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должен вернуться так

```
jbtn.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все же логично! 
Ты перекрасил в свой свой цвет:

```java
jbtn.setBackground(new Color(60, 240, 90));
```

Затем вернуть по дефолту можно так же перекрасив в цвет по умолчанию:

```java
jbtn.setBackground(new Color(голубой градиент));
```